# Justifying that limit of $\frac{\sin(x^{2}+ y^{2})}{x^{2}+ y^{2}} $ as $\mathbf{x} \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

The question asks me to determine if $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x^{2}+ y^{2})}{x^{2}+ y^{2}}$$

exists and if it does to justify it. At first I thought it didn't exist, but after a little tinkering I've decided it does and the limit is $0$. But I'm concerned with my justification fo this being the case.

From one variable calculus we know $|\sin(x)| \leq |x|$. Applying this to the current problem I have: $|\sin(x^{2}+ y^{2})| \leq |x^{2} + y^{2}|$

Having this fact I wanted to use this idea to argue that:

$$\bigg|\frac{\sin(x^{2}+ y^{2})}{x^{2}+ y^{2}}\bigg| \to 0$$

Because $|\sin(x^{2}+ y^{2})|$ would go to 0 faster than $|x^{2} + y^{2}|$ and as such the expression would hold. I'm on the fence about this argument. What is worrying me is the behaviour of $\sin$. Is this the right approach to take?

Comment: $|\sin(x^2+y^2)|$ goes to $0$ faster than $x^2+y^2$? Then why $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin t}t = 1$?

Comment: $\lim$ should be with respect to $(x,y)\to (0,0)$, right?

Comment: As a technicality, the limit you have written now has no meaning. You should write $$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)=\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$$

Comment: Did you mean to leave $y$ out of the limit?

Comment: no @copper.hat I jumped between boldface and regular font. I just changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider two continuous functions $f(x, y)=x^2+y^2$ and $g(t)=\frac{\sin t}{t}$, then we have composition again continuous and limit can be calculated as
$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\sin(x^{2}+ y^{2})}{x^{2}+ y^{2}} = \lim\limits_{t \to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1$$

Comment: I see. I forgot about this expression involving $\sin$. Then I chose the wrong value to be the limit then. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Glad to be helpful.